# Testing Service Spring and mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mockito

I'm trying to learn how to test a Service, but I can't see where the problem is.
My class service is:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    IUserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    IWalletService walletService;

    @Override
    public User createUserAndWallet(NewUserDTO newUser) {

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(newUser.getName());
        user.setSurname(newUser.getSurname());
        user.setBirthdate(newUser.getBirthdate());

        User userCreated = userRepository.save(user);
        walletService.create(userCreated.getId());

        return userCreated;
    }
}
```

My user class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String surname;

    @Column
    private Date birthdate;

}
```

My test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private WalletService walletService;

    @MockBean
    private IUserRepository userRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void test_Create_User() {

        NewUserDTO newUserDTO = new NewUserDTO();
        newUserDTO.setName("Test");
        newUserDTO.setSurname("ApellidoTest");
        newUserDTO.setBirthdate(new Date());

        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Test");
        user.setSurname("ApellidoTest");
        user.setBirthdate(new Date());

        User userCreated = new User();
        user.setId(1);
        user.setName("Test");
        user.setSurname("ApellidoTest");
        user.setBirthdate(new Date());

        Mockito.when(userRepository.save(user)).thenReturn(userCreated);

        User result = userService.createUserAndWallet(newUserDTO);

        assertThat(user, is(result));
    }
}
```

And all the time we have this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.prueba.tests.wallet.model.User.getId()" because "userCreated" is null

    at com.prueba.tests.wallet.service.impl.UserService.createUserAndWallet(UserService.java:31)
    at com.prueba.tests.wallet.service.impl.UserServiceTest.test_Create_User(UserServiceTest.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

I'm trying to use diferents solutions posted in internet but always have the error....

Can you help me to resolve the error and learn to use test?

Thank you!!

Comment: Please post your `User` class, especially equals() method

Comment: posted! @nkrivenko

Comment: Use the debugger and check why the two `User` object are not equal. Probably the `new Date()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rewriting your test like this:

```
Date birthDate = new Date();

...
newUserDTO.setBirthdate(birthDate);

...
user.setBirthdate(birthDate);

User userCreated = new User();
userCreated.setId(1);
userCreated.setName("Test");
userCreated.setSurname("ApellidoTest");
userCreated.setBirthdate(birthDate);

Mockito.when(userRepository.save(user)).thenReturn(userCreated);

User result = userService.createUserAndWallet(newUserDTO);

assertThat(user, is(result));
```

You have three different birth dates, so your mapped user in method `createUserAndWallet` is not equal to the `user` in your test code, assuming your `User.equals` method depends on `birthDate` field.

Comment: That does not solve the nullpointer in `createUserAndWallet()`.

Comment: Why not? Now `userRepository.save(user);` in UserService class returns `null` because it was mocked with different object

Comment: ```
User userCreated = new User();
user.setId(1);
user.setName("Test");
user.setSurname("ApellidoTest");
user.setBirthdate(new Date());
```

You create `userCreated` object but change field values of `user` object. Is this intentional?

Comment: If this is not intentional, then your `user` object is not equal to the one from your service because it has ID, therefore mock will return `null`.

Comment: Yes... this is the problem... TY dude, the problem is the copy-paste! TY!

Answer (score -1):

Your mock for the repository isn't working. You should use a runner for your test to use the `@InjectMocks` annotation, so annotate your test with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.